# Port issue on AWS EC2

Tags: port, firewall, iptables

I am using an EC2 instance for MEAN stack. I have installed an Angular JS application. It runs fine on port 9000. If i type

```
curl localhost:9000
```

I get to see the output. 
When I check it from browser over the internet, it doesn't work. I went to admin panel and opened the port, I had done this earlier from express app for port 3000. I still could not access it from internet. I then checked my express app running on port 3000, it works fine. So I closed that app & changed the port of Angular app to 3000, started again. This time I got "Connection refused error"
Earlier the error used to be "connection timed out". So I restored the port to 9000.

Now I tried opening the port in conventional manner.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

Accidentally ran this command thrice thanks to slow net connection. 
So here's how it looks like.

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

At this point it should have worked, but still stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your network topology looks like, but it looks like your iptables are fine (if triplicated). Check your security groups. Your EC2 instance must have a security group assigned to it and all ports are closed by default. If you want to allow inbound traffic from the internet on port 9000 you'll have to explicitly allow port 9000 on the security group that is associated with the EC2 instance.

If you have an ELB or something else in there then you'll also have to allow that specific traffic on those devices as well.